# RSolve unable to solve the equation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, difference-equations, sequence, convergence

I gave the following code as input:

`RSolve[x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]], x[n], n]`

Mathematica gave the same output:

> `RSolve[x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]], x[n], n]`

I cannot find anything in the documentation. Can someone guide me ?

Comment: Returning the input means: Mathematica isn't able to solve this recursive system

Comment: I doubt that a closed form solution exists. Try to get a couple of values for some initial value using RecurrenceTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extended comment rather than a full answer.

We start by inspecting the `n=0` term

```
x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]] /. n -> 0
```

which yields

> `x[1] == 2 Log[x[0]] + x[0]/2`

Ok, so clearly `x[0]` cannot be zero, but we can set it to some values that are fun and interesting.

> Case 1: `x[0]=e`.

We have

```
list1 = RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]], 
    x[0] == E}, x, {n, 0, 16}] // N
```

The above gives data that are real numbers. We can fit the data to a formula like so:

```
sltnre = FindFit[list1, a Log[b + x] + c, {a, b, c}, x]
```

Now, it is time to check our findings. Note that we are plotting to higher values of `n` compared to the ones used to obtain the fit. We do so in the following manner

```
plot1 = DiscretePlot[(a Log[b + x] + c /. sltnre), {x, 0, 21}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = ListPlot[
   RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]], x[0] == E}, 
     x, {n, 0, 21}] // N, PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image: plot mma1]

We observe that while the fit is not the best possible, it is not all bad. At least not for a first effort. Perhaps you can build up from this point onwards.

> Case 2: `x[0]=1`.

In this case, the data generated by

```
list1 = RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]], 
     x[0] == 1}, x, {n, 0, 16}] // N;
```

are complex numbers. No worries, we just perform two fits for the `Re` and `Im` parts. We proceed as follows:

```
sltnre = FindFit[Re[list1], a Log[x] + b, {a, b}, x]
sltnim = FindFit[Im[list1], a Log[x] + b, {a, b}, x]
```

And the we can check our findings:

```
plot1 = DiscretePlot[(a Log[x] + b /. sltnre), {x, 0, 16}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = ListPlot[Re[list1], PlotStyle -> Black];
plot3 = DiscretePlot[(a Log[x] + b /. sltnim), {x, 0, 16}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green];
plot4 = ListPlot[Im[list1], PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[plot1, plot2]
Show[plot3, plot4]
```

I am not providing any plots, as in this case the fits are really bad, and serious more effort is needed, but again may be a helpful starting point for you.

> Case 3: `x[0]=1`. Proceeding analytically.

We can try to be brave and attempt to achieve analytic progress rather than fitting to numerical data. This requires some time that I do not have, so I am demonstrating the general line of work.

We generate data this time as follows:

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 1/2 x[n] + 2 Log[x[n]], x[0] == 1}, 
   x, {n, 0, 6}] // Expand // TableForm
```

And we focus on the different -structurally- terms that appear in the above data. The task at hand is to try and obtain them analytically. `FindSequenceFunction` is our friend.

We have for the constant term, the one proportional to `I Pi` and the one that goes with `Log[2]` the following:

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16}, n] /. n -> n + 1
FindSequenceFunction[{2 , 1, 1/2, 1/4} I Pi, n] /. n -> n - 1
FindSequenceFunction[-{2, 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8} Log[2], n] /. n -> n - 1
```

and the above give us back

> `2^-n`

> `I 2^(3 - n) π`

> `-2^(3 - n) Log[2]`

In this approach, the general idea is to use some relatively low-lying values of `n` and the `FindSequenceFunction` to try and guess a general pattern and verify it for higher values of `n`. The actual pain -I guess- is the obtain a way to express the terms that start appearing in the `n=6` and higher order that contain increasing number of individual summed pieces. It's not impossible, but it's not the most obvious thing to do.